# How to filter a column in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Let's say I have some timestamp fields in a column that look like this "02-JUL-14 10.36.07.713000000 PM".

Is there a way for me to left-click the column in that table and do a search that contains "JUL" so that I only have rows show up that contain "JUL"?

I have read articles of people saying to include % and ' characters around the word, and using the LIKE ' ' syntax, but nothing has worked out for me.

So in the picture below, I wish I could just type in "JUL", and only rows with the TIME_OF_ENTRY column that contain the letters "JUL" will appear.

I do realize that typing in the filter window below is an EXACT search, but I want to know if there is a way to do a "contains" type of search.

[image]

Comment: What is the datatype of the field?

Comment: Timestamp is the data type

Comment: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/11/sql-developer-quick-tip-filtering-your-data-grids/

Comment: @OldProgrammer
that link shows what I was looking for.
like '%JUL%'
would be the solution. I needed to use both and not just ' ' or % % around the word like I was trying. See if you can put that as an answer and I can mark it as the correct one. thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Paste

```
like '%JUL%'
```

in the filter field, and whatever values in that column which contain "JUL" will show up.

The
http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/11/sql-developer-quick-tip-filtering-your-data-grids/
link from @OldProgrammer contained the solution that I found. There may be more helpful things in that link for more advanced filtering, perhaps.

Answer (score 9):

Type

```
to_char(TIME_OF_ENTRY) like '%JUL%'
```

in the filter field above.

Comment: when I paste this into the filter field, I get no rows returned. Thank you for the suggestion though; it may work in a sql query for all I know.

Answer (score 3):

The statement `` to_char(fieldname) like `%likevalue%` `` worked for me using NetBean 8.0.2. I pasted it into the main filter field at the top of the page with an appropriate fieldname and `likevalue` and made sure that the individual filter fields were cleared. I removed the percent signs when I didn't need them.